# What would happen if the Jews accepted Jesus?

Tags: life-of-jesus, conversion, jews, kingdom-of-heaven

This is just my speculation but would Jesus have established His millennial kingdom on Earth already IF the Jews, on a nationwide basis, accepted Him as their Lord and Saviour?

> "So he said, “A nobleman went to a distant country to **get royal power for himself and then return.** 13 He summoned ten of his slaves, and gave them ten pounds,[a] and said to them, ‘Do business with these until I come back.’ 14 But the citizens of his country hated him and sent a delegation after him, saying, ‘**We do not want this man to rule over us.**’ 15 When he returned, having received royal power, he ordered these slaves, to whom he had given the money, to be summoned so that he might find out what they had gained by trading. 16 The first came forward and said, ‘Lord, your pound has made ten more pounds.’ 17 He said to him, ‘Well done, good slave! Because you have been trustworthy in a very small thing, take charge of ten cities.’ 18 Then the second came, saying, ‘Lord, your pound has made five pounds.’ 19 He said to him, ‘And you, rule over five cities.’ 20 Then the other came, saying, ‘Lord, here is your pound. I wrapped it up in a piece of cloth, 21 for I was afraid of you, because you are a harsh man; you take what you did not deposit, and reap what you did not sow.’ 22 He said to him, ‘I will judge you by your own words, you wicked slave! You knew, did you, that I was a harsh man, taking what I did not deposit and reaping what I did not sow? 23 Why then did you not put my money into the bank? Then when I returned, I could have collected it with interest.’ 24 He said to the bystanders, ‘Take the pound from him and give it to the one who has ten pounds.’ 25 (And they said to him, ‘Lord, he has ten pounds!’) 26 ‘I tell you, to all those who have, more will be given; but from those who have nothing, even what they have will be taken away. 27 But as for these enemies of mine who did not want me to be king over them—bring them here and slaughter them in my presence.’”- Luke 19:12-27

It seems pretty strange that a nobleman would go to some place to get power, only to go back where he came from. Was this due to his subject's contempt (in particular the Pharisees since these rebels sent a **delegation**) of this nobleman, which was further intensified in verse 14, even **AFTER** this nobleman declared his intention to leave this nation?

And considering that Jesus was prophesised to be the ultimate atoning sacrifice for humanity, would the Jews have been willing to sacrifice Him? Or would God have the Romans do the dirty job?

Comment: "*It seems pretty strange that a nobleman would go to some place to get power*" -- Not so strange.  E.g. when new Governor Generals are appointed, they visit the sovereign.  In the case of Canada, GG Julie Payette travelled to London to meet Queen Elizabeth.  "*The sovereign will also hold an audience with the appointee and will at that time induct both the governor general-designate and his or her spouse into the Order of Canada as Companions, as well as appointing the former as a Commander of ...*" -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Governor_General_of_Canada#Appointment)

Comment: No I meant going to a place to be appointed as king and then promptly returning back home as if "nothing" happened, as indicated by the nobleman trying to assign minas to his servants/slaves in his "absence" RIGHT after he tried to gain royal power (was he concerned about the hateful delegation and thus, made a hasty departure??). It's like showing up to a party and saying to your friends five mins later, "gotta go home in the meantime, cya".

Answer (score 2):

**What would happen if the Jews accepted Jesus?**

Some Christians associate the conversion of the Jewish nation with an **end of time event**. WE can not speculate as to when or how this may or may not happen. In any case any Jews that do convert will obviously be saved and see Jesus in Heaven themselves.

> The widespread **conversion of the Jews** to Christianity is a future event predicted by many Christians, often as an end time event. Some Christian groups consider the conversion of the Jews to be imperative and pressing and make it their mission to bring this about. However, since the Middle Ages, the Christian Church has formally upheld Constitution pro Judæis (Formal Statement on the Jews), which stated:
>
> > We decree that no Christian shall use violence to force them [the Jews] to be baptized, so long as they are unwilling and refuse. ...
>
> In the New Testament
>
> The biblical basis for this expectation is found in Romans [11:25-26](https://www.biblica.com/bible/?osis=niv:Romans.11:25%E2%80%9311:26):
>
> > I do not want you to be ignorant of this mystery, brothers, so that you may not be conceited: Israel has experienced a hardening in part until the full number of the Gentiles has come in. And so all Israel will be saved... ([NIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_International_Version)).
>
> The meaning of Romans 11:25-26a has been disputed. Douglas J. Moo calls Romans 11:26a "the storm center in the interpretation of [Romans 9-11](https://www.biblica.com/bible/?osis=niv:Romans.9%E2%80%9311) and of New Testament teaching about the Jews and their future." Moo himself interprets the passage as predicting a "large-scale conversion of Jewish people at the end of this age" through "faith in the gospel of Jesus their Messiah".
>
> [Pope Benedict XVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Benedict_XVI) in his book Jesus of Nazareth: Holy Week (2011) has suggested that the church should not be targeting Jews for conversion efforts, since "Israel is in the hands of God, who will save it ‘as a whole’ at the proper time." - [Conversion of the Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_the_Jews)

Many Church Fathers and saints have written on the end times conversion of the Jews:

> "Their sins occasioned the salvation of the Gentiles and again the incredulity of the Gentiles will occasion the conversion of Israel. You will find both in the Apostle (St. Paul)." - St. Jerome
>
> "Paul insists that only a part of Israel has been hardened, for many of them believe.  He thus encourages them not to despair that others will be saved as well.  After the Gentiles accepted the gospel, the Jews would believe, when the great Elijah would come to them and bring them the doctrine of the faith.  The Lord himself said as much: 'Elijah will come and will restore all things.'" - Theodoret
>
> "The blindness of the Jews will endure until the fullness of the gentiles have accepted the faith.  And this is in accord with what the Apostle says below about the salvation of the Jews, namely, that after the fullness of the nations have entered, 'all Israel will be saved', not individually as at present, but universally." ...
>
> "What, I say, will such an admission effectuate, if not that it bring the Gentiles back to life? The Gentiles would be the believers whose faith has grown cold, or even that the totality, deceived by the Antichrist, fall and are restored to their pristine fervor by the admission of the Jews." - St. Thomas Aquinas
>
> “Whereas the Jews are made to the image of God, and a remnant of them will one day be saved, and whereas they have sought our protection: following in the footsteps of our predecessors We command that they be not molested in their synagogues; that their laws, rights and customs be not assailed; that they be not baptized by force, constrained to observe Christian festivals, nor to wear new badges, and that they be not hindered in their business relations with Christians.” - Pope Martin V, Declaration on the Protection of the Jews, 1419
>
> [Salvation is from the Jews](https://www.salvationisfromthejews.com/endtimes.html)